# Android - dynamically adding view to popup dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an Alert Dialog that shows some text input fields.
When I enter data and click "OK", it saves this data and displays it in a custom view on the Activity that called the dialog.

If I want to edit this data, I click on the custom view and the same alert dialog pops up. I want to pre-populate the data, and allow editing, and adding new data. However, here is where I'm having a problem.

When I try to do add the existing data to the dialog, the views get added to the top of the view, and not the subview I want them added to. See here:

[image: Populated View show be under the headings]

So the alert dialog inflates the view from my Activity:

```
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.material_add_dialog, viewGroup, false);
builder.setView(dialogView);
```

But this `R.layout.material_add_dialog` is the main/top view.

I have a custom adapter class that I am using as well. Here is the `getView()` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(mInflater).inflate(R.layout.add_material_popup_dialog_row, null);
    }

    Material material = mMaterials.get(position);

    EditText etMaterial = convertView.findViewById(R.id.material_add_text_material);
    EditText etSupplier = convertView.findViewById(R.id.material_add_text_supplier);
    EditText etWeight = convertView.findViewById(R.id.material_add_text_weight);
    EditText etAmount = convertView.findViewById(R.id.material_add_text_amount);

    etMaterial.setText(material.getMaterial());
    etSupplier.setText(material.getSupplier());
    etWeight.setText(material.getUnit());
    etAmount.setText(material.getAmount());

    return convertView;
}
```

So if you see `convertView`, this is inflating `R.layout.add_material_popup_dialog_row` which is the row that is being added at the top.

So really my question is, how can I add this row to a subview of the dialogs view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get, or create, the subview. If it exists:

```
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.material_add_dialog, viewGroup, false);
View subView = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.mySubViewId);
```

Or, you can create a new view and add it to the current view:

```
//You would need to create the appropriate view for your use-case.
View view = new View();
dialogView.addView(view);
```

Comment: Its my understanding that the `getView()` method in the adapter builds the view/row and adds it to the view set in `builder.setView(dialogView);`. So I need advice on how to intercept that process in the adapter, I think...

Comment: Can you post your XML for the dialog view?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create the container `LinearLayout as root` then `addView(convertView)` and `return root`